# JW Player in the form of a popup: Player doesn't load on second pop

Tags: jquery, popup, jwplayer

So, I'm trying to make a single page list with thumbnails, and when you click on them..video will basically popup. I'm using as a player the latest JW Player (5.8) and latest jQuery.

Everything works well, however, only on the first "pop". When I close my first "pop" and open a new video, the player doesn't load.

I first though, that the problem is, that I'm `.remove()`'ing the player-container (for the obvious reason, that videos wont stay playing on the background and/or that videos wouldn't get mixed up generally). However it wasn't the `.remove()`.

My plugin-function to pop the videos is:

```
$.fn.AllfilmVideoPopper = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        var permalink = $(this);

        $(permalink).click(function () {
            $('body').append(
                $body_overlay = $('<div class="body_overlay" />').append(
                    $wrapper = $('<div id="video_popper_wrapper">').append(
                        $closing_button = $('<div id="video_close" />'),
                        $player = $('<div id="video_popper" />')
                    ).centerit()
                )
            );
            $body_overlay.fadeIn();

            jwplayer("video_popper").setup({
                flashplayer: vp_video_player,
                file: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrjwaqZfjIY',
                width: 800,
                height: 400,
                skin: vp_video_skin
            });

            $closing_button.click(function () {
                $body_overlay.fadeOut('fast', function () {
                    // $player.remove();
                })
            });

            return false;
        });

    });
};
```

<sup>Code is still raw, as I'm developing it. With only one test video</sup>

**Note:** `vp_video_player` and `vp_video_skin` are predefined JW Player files related parameters, that basically include the CMS's theme-location to the player.swf and skin location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I did, was I created a standalone page, that has JW Player in it. Only thing PHP in it, is the $_GET['vid'] to the source-file-video-file-url.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Video</title>
    <style>
        html, body {height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: #000000;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer("player").setup({
            flashplayer: "player.swf",
            file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<?= $_GET['vid'] ?>",
            width: 800,
            height: 400,
            skin: "glow.zip"
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I modifed my launcher script's 1 line:

```
$player = $('<div id="video_popper" />')
```

to

```
$player = $('<iframe src="iframe.php?vid=' + vid + '" id="video_popper"></iframe>')
```

Then removed the original player-loading-function alltogether
jwplayer("video_popper").setup(); // etc..

And it basically seems to work like I originally wanted. And no pre-generated hidden on the background content is needed for this, as iframes are pretty outdated, however still dynamical in their nature.

See it working here: http://www.alta.ee/groomlake/jw-player-popup-problem/video-list.html